# Is the output from ssh guaranteed to be retrieved?

Tags: go, ssh, output, buffer

I use the [ssh package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210813211128-0a44fdfbc16e/ssh) to connect to a Linux server and retrieve the output of commands. The helper function I wrote for that is below:

```golang
func sshRunCommand(host string, command string) (output string, err error) {
    keyData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("srv.private.openssh")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    key, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(keyData)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // Authentication
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "root",
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeys(key),
        },
    }
    // Connect
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(host, "22"), config)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // Create a session. It is one session per command.
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer session.Close()
    var b bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &b //  this is the place I am concerned with
    // Finally, run the command
    err = session.Run(command)
    return b.String(), err
}
```

This command usually works fine: it always connects but randomly does not return the output.

Before going further in my investigations, **I wanted to make sure that the output buffer is flushed before returning the output. Is this the case?**

Comment: If the OS is Linux, only stderr is guaranteed to be flushed, not stdout AFAIK.

Comment: Try checking stderr for any output there too. Any io problems are expected to be returned as an error from `Session.Run`.

Answer (score 0):

In this use-case/issue, you can see stdout *and* stderr being linked to the same buffer.
See if that helps in your case.

```
    sess, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create session: ", err)
    }
    defer sess.Close()

    stdin, err := sess.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    sess.Stdout = &b
    sess.Stderr = &b

    err = sess.Shell()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ...

    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(stdin, "%s\n", cmd)
```